# drop down menu bootsrap 3 wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a navbar with a drop down menu for mobile phones.
I've did this for some other websites and it always worked fine.

Now all of a sudden it stopped working and I wonder why..

This is the code:

```
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Marco Koopman</a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My school</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">More info</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"/>

</body>
```

Comment: `jQuery` must come first in order otherwise all bootstrap js is not going to work...

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery` must come first in order and proper close `script` tags as your 2nd `script` tag is not properly closed.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>


<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Marco Koopman</a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="">About me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My school</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">More info</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```